# quit method in python unittests raises ConnectionResetError using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I have a class for Integration Test using Selenium for Chrome Webdriver like this

```py
LoginTest.py
class LoginTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    browser = CommonTest.set_up_webdriver()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(LoginTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.browser.maximize_window()
        cls.browser_url = cls.live_server_url
        cls.browser.get(cls.browser_url)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(LoginTest, cls).tearDownClass()
        time.sleep(3)
        cls.browser.quit() # Error here

    def setUp(self):
        super(LoginTest, self).setUp()
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        super(LoginTest, self).tearDown()
```

```py
CommonTest.py
class CommonTest:
    @staticmethod
    def set_up_webdriver():
        options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

        return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Environment.CHROME_DRIVER_WINDOWS_PATH, options=options,
                                    service_log_path=ConstTest.TEST_LOG_PATH)
```

When I remove line `cls.browser.quit()` my Test working OK. But It doesn't close Chrome Browser.
If I add line `cls.browser.quit()` It will get error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have search for error `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` many time and add many solution but It's still got that error

Answer (score 1):

When using [python-unittest](/questions/tagged/python-unittest) as per the current implementation the [service](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L174) will be stoped once your script ends as, `subprocess.Popen` doesn't send signal on `__del__`, so the attempt is to close the launched process when `__del__` is triggered.

```
def __del__(self):
    # `subprocess.Popen` doesn't send signal on `__del__`;
    # so we attempt to close the launched process when `__del__`
    # is triggered.
    try:
        self.stop()
    except Exception:
        pass
```